# AngularJS not selecting integer values

Tags: angularjs, types

Does anyone know why AngularJS not selecting options on `<select multiple>` if `ng-model` is an array of `integer`?

```
$scope.selected = [1, 3]
$scope.options = [
  {id: 1, title: 'option 1'},
  {id: 2, title: 'option 2'},
  {id: 3, title: 'option 3'}
]
```

Everything works just fine if `$scope.selected = ['1', '3']` is array of `string`. I need to get it working without using `ng-options`.

Here is JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/maxflex/3jfk8/19/

Comment: From the docs "Note that the value of a select directive used without ngOptions is always a string. When the model needs to be bound to a non-string value, you must either explicitly convert it using a directive (see example below) or use ngOptions to specify the set of options. This is because an option element can only be bound to string values at present." https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: why you don't want to convert `$scope.selected` to an array of string? you can later do `options[Number(selectedValue)]` to get selected title

Comment: @camden_kid thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Still seems strange though.